# Faithful direct image functor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. When is the direct image functor $f_\ast:\mathbf{Shv}(\mid X\mid) \to \mathbf{Shv}(\mid Y\mid)$ faithful, full, or essentially surjective?

Hints and references would be appreciated.

Comment: Which type of sheaves are you working with?

Comment: @DoriBejleri: I am working with sheaves of rings.

Comment: When $f$ is a closed immersion this questions are answered [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00AF).

Also when $f$ is the immersion (of a locally closed set) $f_*$ is faithfull: This is true for immersion of closed sets for the reference above. It is also true for open immersions because if $i:U\rightarrow X$ is the inclusion of an open set we have $(i_*\mathcal{O}_U)|_U=\mathcal{O}_U$. The locally closed case follows by composition.

Comment: I am sorry that I have to say this, sadly the above cited statement on the stacksproject only applies to the non-derived direct image functor. The general direct image functor, even of a clossed immersion does not need to be faithful or full in general.